# Why I'm getting Stream<Object> when I call stream() after collect()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following example, which is not compiled:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, -3, 8);

        list.stream()
                .filter(x -> x > 0)
                .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)
                .stream() // Stream<Object>
                .map(x -> x * 2)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If I replace

```
.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)
```

with

```
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The code will be compiled.
So the question is how do I write `collect()` with supplier and accumulator(I need it) to be able to call a `stream()` after it?

Comment: It's because of the raw type `ArrayList`. Use `ArrayList<Integer>::new`

Comment: Like @ernest_k said. Since you didn't specified ArrayList generics type, the compiler will assume it is an Object since everything in Java is an Object.

Comment: If you enable all compiler warnings, you will be notified of things like this, rather than being surprised by them.

Comment: rgettman already said it — it's because the compiler is unable to infer the argument type. `ArrayList<Integer>::new` is not always required, for instance, `List<Integer> anotherList = list.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)` will just work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you've made a raw method reference to the `ArrayList` constructor with `ArrayList::new`.

The type argument was not inferred with:

```
.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)
```

The [3-argument overload of `collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) expects 3 arguments, the first one being a `Supplier<R>`.  At this point there is no connection between the `collect` method's type argument `R` and `T` which is `Integer` here.  The only way to infer this would be through the second argument, a `BiConsumer<R, ? super T>`.  Here you have `ArrayList::add`, which gives the compiler no way to infer `R` either.

You must supply what `R` is in the first argument, the Supplier.  You can supply explicit type arguments to the class to create on a method reference.

```
.collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)
```

This compiles, and the output is as expected:

```
2
4
16
```

When you use [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()), you are supplying only one argument.

> `public static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toList()`

Here, there is only one type argument `T`, so the compiler can correctly infer that this `T` is `Integer`, so a `List<Integer>` is created, allowing the code to compile.  The type arguments to the `Collector` returned bind `T` to `List<T>`, allowing the compiler to perform the type inference.

Note that this is only necessary in the first place because there is no target type to help with type inference; you continue with the stream manipulation and just call `System.out.println` at the end, which can take an `Object`.

If you had this code:

```
List<Integer> modified = list.stream()
            .filter(x -> x > 0)
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

Then target type inference would have supplied `Integer` for the type argument to `ArrayList::new`.  This compiles also.